# Creating a multi level drill down iphone app with detail view using SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iphone app development and was looking for a good tutorial demonstration how to use SQLite in a multi level drill down table view with a detail view.

I've searched the web for tutorials but could only find bits and pieces of code which tend to get confusing.

My SQLite table with work on the basis of a category id and if there are multiple results for a category id, a table view would show else if only one result, then the detail view of any selected table cell.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do a master-detail view. XCode has a good template for such a view. A quick search on "ios master detail sample code" shows lots of responses to get some sample code. The SQLite DB would be used to populate the tables. I like to fill an NSMutableArray with the data from the database and then use that to populate the data.

It would also be good to watch the WWDC videos on Storyboards. That will help you understand segues better.